# non-trivial convergent sequence

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> **In the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$, there is no non-trivial convergent sequence.**

Assume $R=(\mathcal{U}_{n})_{n}$ is a sequence of distinct ultrafilters on some set $X$. Since every Hausdorff space has an infinite discrete subspace, there is a subsequence $(\mathcal{V}_{n})_{n}$ of $(\mathcal{U}_{n})_{n}$ such that $\{\mathcal{V}_{n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a discrete subspace of $\beta X$. In particular, there is a sequence $(A_{n})_{n}$ of sets with $A_{n}\in\mathcal{V}_{m}$ if and only if $m=n$. If we let $B_{n}=A_{n}\setminus(A_{0}\cup \dotsm \cup A_{n-1})$, then the sequence $(B_{n})_{n}$ is pairwise disjoint and $B_{n}\in\mathcal{V}_{m}$ iff $m=n$. If we let $B=\bigcup_{n}B_{2n}$, then $B\in\mathcal{V}_{m}$ if and only if $m$ is even. In other words, if $\mathcal{B}=\{\mathcal{V}\in\beta X \mid B\in\mathcal{V}\}$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is a clopen set with $\mathcal{V}_{m}\in\mathcal{B}$ iff $m$ is even. Therefore, we conclude that the sequence $(\mathcal{V}_{m})_{m}$ cannot converge to any point, so the sequence $(\mathcal{U}_{n})_{n}$ cannot converge to any point either.

> (1)  **Non-trivial** convergent sequence means **constant** convergent sequence ??
>
> (2) Why can he say:
>
> (a) If we let $B_{n}=A_{n}\setminus(A_{0}\cup \dotsm\cup A_{n-1})$, then the sequence $(B_{n})_{n}$ is pairwise disjoint and $B_{n}\in\mathcal{V}_{m}$ iff $m=n$. ?
>
> (b) If $\mathcal{B}=\{\mathcal{V}\in\beta X \mid B\in\mathcal{V}\}$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is a **clopen set** with $\mathcal{V}_{m}\in\mathcal{B}$ iff $m$ is even? What does it mean clopen set??

Comment: Your question seems to quote part of a text book or an article. If this is the case, it would be a good idea to add a reference.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin This seems to be quote from [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/138201/8250) on MO. (It would be better if the OP would mention that.)

Answer (score 1):

(1) "Trivial" means "constant after some point".

(2a) The $B_n$ are clearly disjoint. If $m\neq n$ then $B_n\not\in \mathcal V_m$ because $B_n\subset A_n$ and $A_n\not\in\mathcal V_m$. If $m=n$ then $A_i\notin\mathcal V_m$ for all $i=0,\dots ,n-1$, so $X\setminus A_i\in\mathcal V_m$ (since $\mathcal V_m$ is an ultrafilter) and hence $B_n=A_n\cap\left( \bigcap_{i=0}^{n-1} (X\setminus A_i)\right)\in\mathcal V_m$.

(2b) "Clopen" means "closed and open".

Comment: Thanksyou for answering. But why is $ \mathcal{B}$ the clopen set? for this reason , can we say the sequence $(V_ m )_ m$ cannot converge to any point? and $(\mathcal{U}_n)_n$ is constant?

Comment: $\mathcal B$ is open just by definition of the topology of $\beta X$; and its complement is also open because it is $\{ \mathcal V;\; X\setminus B\in\mathcal V\}$. Now assume that the sequence $(\mathcal V_m)$ is convergent, say $\mathcal V_m\to \mathcal V$. Then $\mathcal V$ is either in $\mathcal B$ or in $\beta X\setminus\mathcal B$, and since both are open this implies that either all but finitely $\mathcal V_m$ are in $\mathcal B$, or all but finitely many $\mathcal V_m$ are not in $\mathcal B$; but this is a contradiction.

Comment: For (1), you means to say that "trivial" means "constant after some point".

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks for pointing out the typo...