# Topological spaces with nontrivial convergent sequence

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let $X$ be a (Hausdorff) topological space for which there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ and an element $x$ taking values in $X$ such that $\lim_n x_n=x$ and $x_n \neq x$ for all integers $n$.

Does a topological space with this property have a known name? Or I should refer just as a "nontrivial" topological space?

Comment: I've never seen a name for this, but I don't think "nontrivial" is an appropriate name.  There are certainly spaces whose topology is quite nontrivial but which do not satisfy this condition.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the comment: in case, do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: I would just say "Let $X$ be a topological space with a non-trivial convergent sequence."

Comment: @AJStas Thank you, probably it is the best solution. Here there is an example where no nontrivial convergent sequences exist: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477829/non-trivial-convergent-sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen used in papers: "$X$ has a non-trivial convergent sequence" which is the obvious and self-explaining name.

It's obeyed by any infinite first countable $T_1$ space with a non-isolated point. So most spaces will have it. Not discrete spaces or weird ones like $\beta \omega\setminus \omega = \omega^\ast$.

Answer (score 0):

Such a topological space with this property has no specific name.

Take for example $(\mathbb{R},d)$ where $d$ is the usual metric and take te sequence $x_n=1/n$ which converges to $0$ but $x_n \neq 0,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Also take the space $(C[0,1],d_{\infty})$ whre $d_{\infty}$ is supremum/uniform metric.

In this space the set of polynomial functions is dense.

Thus for every continuous function in $[0,1]$ that is not a polynomial we can find a sequence of polynomials converging to it.(Weierstrass Theorem).

Comment: This is fine that these spaces have no specific name :) But what is the meaning of these examples? Of course, most of the topological spaces satisfy this property

Comment: they are just examples of spaces with this property..As i said in the beggining   there is  no name for this property..Also in many metric spaces from the definition of accumulations points we can find such sequence..So a part of the property you mention in your post  coincides with the definition of an accumulation(not limit point) point in many metric spaces..In a discrete space we cannot find such sequences